# how to remap a key to scroll half page up in vim?

Tags: vim

By default, pressing `Ctrl+D` will scroll half page up.

I'd like to remap `Ctrl-E` to scroll half page up such that it's easy to scroll page up and down with just `Ctrl-E` and `Ctrl-D`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

This line will do it:

```
nnoremap <c-e> <c-u>
```

But you will lose the original function of `C-E`, which I think is pretty useful with `C-Y` too.

I suggest you get used to `Ctrl-D(own)` and `Ctrl-U(p)`.

Comment: nice. Thanks. I've been used to Ctrl-U for ten years :). I just wanted to redesign my entire muscle memory.

Comment: I agree with Leo. <c-u> is a different hand, a different finger, and a different row. The mnemonic benefit is spurious given hjkl movement keys.